# Adding cron to a Docker image

Tags: docker

I created a Docker container from the python image to host a Django project. Now I'd like to run some cron jobs to update data in the Django project.

However, since I created it using the [python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) image, cron isn't available.

I'm still new to Docker, so I'm not sure what the easiest route is. Should I try to add cron functionality to the python image, or should I switch to a more general image, like [Ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/), which will allow me to issue the standard `apt install cron` command?

I see there's also [cron](https://hub.docker.com/r/prima/cron/) and [crontab](https://hub.docker.com/r/willfarrell/crontab/) images as well. Does Docker support overlaying multiple images, say python+crontab, or would it be easier to just use Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi, because there was no feedback from you, I just wanted to ask. Is my answer sufficient? Does this work for you? Regards Radek.

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of docker is that you can take already existing image and adjust it to your own needs. There is no need to make from scratch. Iguess the easiest route would be the one which requires the smallest amount of steps or simply suits you the most.

#### First option - Dockerfile

Let's assume you use `python:latest` tag, then create your own image with cron like so:

```
FROM python:latest
LABEL maintainer="John Doe"

RUN apt-get install -y update && \
    apt-get install -y cron && \
    apt-get clean all
```

Really easy right? And you don't have to worry about installing python and Django dependencies on ubuntu image (There would be much more steps than just simply installing one app). Now you need to build this image:

```
docker build --tag 'foo-image:latest' --no-cache /path/to/dockerfile
```

Now you can use foo-image which will have cron installed and has everything what python image has.

If you need to do more with cron besides installing it can be also added into Dockerfile. But I don't know any specifics of your use case.

**Second option - docker commit**

1. Run container of python image
2. Exec into it
3. Do your adjustments (Instal, run a process, add user etc.)
4. Commit this container it to a new image

Dummy example of [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_commit/):

```
$ docker run -dit --name=Nginx -p 80:80 nginx
68188c608160754736f192d535742b9d0dfbc3c09564c1731741c08c211b219f
$ docker exec -it Nginx /bin/bash
root@68188c608160:/# touch New_file
root@68188c608160:/# apt-get update     
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Ign:1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                   
Get:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [454 kB]
Get:4 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
Get:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2434 B]              
Get:7 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [5152 B]
Get:8 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7099 kB]
Fetched 7864 kB in 4s (1767 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
root@68188c608160:/# exit
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
68188c608160        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   Nginx
$ docker commit Nginx nginx-updated:latest
sha256:dcc2f09f523eded0b2d33abb47e99b83453c12fb6ba958b441111f9ff40c5a8a
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx-updated                                                     latest              dcc2f09f523e        3 seconds ago       156MB
nginx
```

For me, I prefer to use Dockerfiles. I only use 2nd option when I'm not sure what steps needs to be done to do certain use case. But anyways afterward I'll still add those changes into Dockerfile.